# Can I safely kill a ton of my /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start PIDs?

Tags: apache, tcp, kill, munin

Is it "safe" to mass-kill every PID on my websites-serving dedi (debian squeeze) matching this (I know this is Apache's) ?
www-data /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

I'll spare you the details, but these PIDs are the ultimate non-removed remnants of an intrusion, there are still maaaaany more than needed that are running and my dedi's got far too many "ESTABLISHED" connexions, local ipconntrack, TCP opening connexions and reset connexions per second as seen in netstat, "established : connections through firewall", several indicators I see in Munin are still way off the chart.

I'd be tempted to mass-close them all, but I don't know if 
- that can "break" something important that won't restart by itself, or if 
- that will only mean that the the browsers on computers elsewhere across the internet will suddenly stop receiving data and will have require hitting F5

Thanks if you can tell me ! :)

Comment: If you've had an intrusion you should certainly have restarted the entire system.

Answer (score 5):

You can kill them if you want. If they are busy processing connections from one or more HTTP clients, those connections will be broken. If they are idle waiting for new connections then they will die gracefully, but in that case Apache's main process will probably restart them because it wants to keep a certain number of spare servers around (configuration parameter `MinSpareServers`).

If you have more spare servers than you need, then a better idea would be to tune down the Apache configuration parameter `MaxSpareServers`. If you do that and reload Apache, Apache will kill the excess processes all by itself.

Just don't kill the Apache main process. That's the one which is the parent process of all the other ones and whose own parent process ID is 1. If you kill that one then Apache will shut down.

Comment: Thanks for the reassuring confirmation, Celada ! However, do you know how I can "recognize" which one of these is the main Apache process ? I was going to use my virtualmin's list of PIDs to export it to a text file, and then paste it to putty as kill -9, as things are, I honestly don't know how to find which one is "the original Apache", I'd have to open every single one of the PID's details page to find the parent, it would take a day...

Comment: If you use the `-f` or `-l` option to `ps`, there is a PPID (parent process ID) column. The main Apache process is the one whose process ID appears in the PPID column of all the others, i.e. the main process is the parent of all the others. The main Apache process' own PPID is normally equal to 1.

Comment: Also: no need to jump straight to `kill -9`. Try regular kill first, which will give the processes a chance to clean up. Reserve `kill -9` (`kill -KILL`) for cases where a process refuses to die and you really do want to kill it harshly without giving it any chance to clean up.

Comment: I wouldn't even bother killing the main process. In fact given "remnants of an intrusion", I'd `killall -9 apache` without wasting a thought. One can always type `/etc/init.d/apache start` any time later if desired.